# How to change mobile menu respond width?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In prestashop 1.7 moble menu is active from 768 screen size . I need to change this size to 991 . How to change this ? Also there is anyway to know viewport size in tpl.

Comment: are you using bootstrap css??

Comment: Yes bootstrap css using

Answer (score 1):

You can use this piece of css if you are using bootstrap.css

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
        position: static;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        line-height: 20px;
    }
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
        padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
    }
    .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 20px;
        clear: both;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #333;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        /*margin: 7.5px -15px;*/
        margin: 7.5px 50px 7.5px -15px
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .navbar-text {
        float: none;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
    /* since 3.1.0 */
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
        display: block!important;
    }
    .collapsing {
        overflow: hidden!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working menu link showing 900px but onclick menu not showing. Menu showing after 768 px .

Comment: is it live ? can you share the url

Comment: Skype id please or email id

Answer (score 1):

Edit your **/prestashop/themes/[theme]/assets/js/theme.js** file.

Search for `768` or `default.responsive.min_width` and replace the numeric value with your pixel value.